# Emacs 24.4 no longer highlights keywords in `M-x run-python`

Tags: font-lock, python, comint

With Emacs 24.3 I get certain keywords highlighted in an inferior Python buffer:

[image]

This is no longer the case for Emacs 24.4:

[image]

What could possibly cause this? I've made sure it's not my configuration by running `emacs -q` and am not sure whether font-locking generally changed or the packaged `python.el` has regressed.

Comment: Might be intentional. It looks like regular words were being wrongly highlighted as keywords.

Comment: I very much doubt this since `font-lock-defaults` is `(python-font-lock-keywords nil nil nil nil)` which define all kinds of error classes as builtins.

Comment: It still highlights text you write on the prompt, right? Seems the highlighting has been turned off on messages, somehow. Which seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes, those still get highlighted. Still, I'm interested in what exactly changed for the output functions.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's on purpose, and it even requires some ugly/tricky code to get this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's intentional, since the old behaviour isn't really what you'd want. C-h n gives:

```
* Changes in Specialized Modes and Packages in Emacs 24.4
...
*** Python mode
...
*** Automatic shell prompt detection.  New user options:
**** `python-shell-interpreter-interactive-arg'.
**** `python-shell-prompt-detect-enabled'.
**** `python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning'.
**** `python-shell-prompt-input-regexps'.
**** `python-shell-prompt-output-regexps'.
```

That could possibly be related?

Comment: I've checked by looking for your options and it looks like the derived inferior Python mode makes sure both input and output aren't font-locked which avoids the problem of stray quotes fontifying your current prompt. Therefore, I'll accept your answer for leading me on to the right path behind this mystery.